# Matlab ode45 Does Not Terminate When Event Occurs

Tags: matlab

When solving an ODE with MATLAB's `ode45` solver, I'm trying to trigger an event to terminate the solution when a (general) boolean condition is satisfied. For example, in the code below, the condition is that `x > 1.5` (because events trigger when value is zero, that is, when `x <= 1.5` is false). Starting the solution from a point where the condition is satisfied at time zero, but is not satisfied immediately afterward, causes the event to never be triggered. What's going on? Is this a bug in zero-crossing detection? I know that zero-crossing is easier when using continuous values, but I would expect the solver to still work in this case, albeit slower.

```
f = @(t, x) 1;
tspan = [0, 10];
x0 = 1.5;
[t, x] = ode45(f, tspan, x0, odeset('Events',@zeroevents)); 

x(end)                   % Value is 11.5 
assert(x(end) <= 1.5001) % This assertion fails.
    
function [value,isterminal,direction] = zeroevents(t, x)
    isterminal = 1;
    direction = 0;
    value = x <= 1.5;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is likely due to two of the three [limitations of event detection](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ode-event-location.html#bu7whe8):

> - If a terminal event occurs during the first step of the integration, then the solver registers the event as nonterminal and continues integrating.

and

> - Zeros are determined by sign crossings between steps. Therefore, zeros of functions with an even number of crossings between steps can be missed.

So the first firing of the event is ignored by-definition, despite the initial condition satisfying the requirements. And since your value is calculated through a boolean expression, it never exhibits a sign-change and therefore never fires a detection.

Changing your problem to fire an event after the initial step and calculating the value through a signed residual (i.e., `value = x - 1.5;`) should produce the behavior you are looking for. If how the value is approached matters (i.e., from above/positive or from below/negative), the direction value should be set appropriately; a direction of zero fires on either approach.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to simply manually check whether the stopping condition is satisfied at the second time in the solution. If it is not, then I truncate the rest of the solution.
f = @(t, x) 1;
tspan = [0, 10];
x0 = 1.5;
[t, x] = ode45(f, tspan, x0, odeset('Events',@zeroevents));

```
x(end) % Value is 11.5 

% Truncate the rest of the solution.
if isStop(x(2)) 
    t = t(1:2);
    x = x(1:2);
end

x(end) % Value is ~1.57
    
function [value,isterminal,direction] = zeroevents(t, x)
    isterminal = 1;
    direction = 0;
    value = isStop(x);
end

function stop = isStop(x)
    stop = x > 1.5;
end
```

This is not a great solution, however, because `ode45` picks a relatively large timestep because it doesn't "notice" the event, so `x(2)` is significantly larger than `1.5` (around `1.57`). To fix this, we can manually calculate `x(2)` using linear extrapolation with a small time-step:

```
if isStop(x(2))
    delta_t = 1e-10;
    t1 = t(1);
    t2 = t1 + delta_t;
    t = [t1; t2];
    x1 = x(1);
    x2 = x1 + delta_t * f(x1, t1);
    x = [x1'; x2'];
end
```

Comment: I'll note that in the [limitations section](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ode-event-location.html#bu7whe8), the following advice is offered: "If the solver steps past events, try reducing `RelTol` and `AbsTol` to improve accuracy. Alternatively, set `MaxStep` to place an upper bound on the step size. Adjusting `tspan` does not change the steps taken by the solver."

Comment: Reducing the tolerance and max step size only works if you know _a priori_ that an event will happen. In my case, however, I'm developing a library so I need the event detection to work without requiring users to tweak simulation parameters.